# Can a non-unitary process be made unitary using a transformation or by expanding the phase space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, time-evolution, unitarity, linear-systems

Suppose I have a matrix differential equation:

$$ \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = A\mathbf{x}$$

The solution to this is

$$\mathbf{x}(t) = e^{At}\mathbf{x}(0)$$

If $A^{\dagger}=-A$, then the time evolution operator $e^{At}$ is unitary. But if that's not the case, is there a way to make the time evolution unitary, either by doing a variable transformation (i.e., $\mathbf{x} = B\mathbf{y}$ for some invertible $B$) or by expanding the phase space such that the system above is embedded in a larger, unitary system?

Could we do this for any system? If not, what conditions allow us to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if that's not the case, is there a way to make the time evolution unitary, either by doing a variable transformation (i.e., =
> for some invertible 
> )

A mathematical change of variables cannot change the probabilities for physically observable events to occur. Non-unitarity implies that the probability of all possible final states for at least some process does not sum to 1. Since that is phrased in terms of physically observable probabilities, it cannot depend on the choice of variables we use to represent the system, so changing variables cannot make a non-unitary system become unitary.

A more mathematical argument is that unitarity is a property of an operator, and does not depend on the basis in which we express that operator.

> or by expanding the phase space such that the system above is embedded in a larger, unitary system?

On the other hand, this is actually quite a common scenario. For example, you might represent an unstable nucleus with a Hamiltonian that does not include the decay products as degrees of freedom. Then the system is non-unitary. One way this manifests itself is that the probability for ground state of the nucleus to remain in the ground state will decay exponentially. If the system is prepared in the ground state with energy $E_0$ at time $t=0$, so the initial state is $|E_0, t=0\rangle$, then the probability that it will still be in the ground state at time $T$ is $|\langle E_0, t=T | E_0, t=0 \rangle|^2 \sim e^{- \Gamma T}$, where $\Gamma$ is the decay rate. By enlarging the Hilbert space to include the decay products, the full space of the nucleus plus possible decay products can be unitary. (Provided you've included all relevant states that can be accessed by the system in the Hilbert space).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Andrew. To address your first point, let's say you're given a matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}0& 1+\alpha  \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, where $\alpha > -1$. Clearly this matrix isn't anti-Hermitian unless $\alpha = 0$. But if I transform the variables using $B = \begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\ 0& 1/\sqrt{1+\alpha}\end{bmatrix}$, I obtain an anti-Hermitian matrix. Can't we do something like this for other matrices too?

Comment: And to address your second comment, is there a general mathematical procedure that allows us to do this? Or is it dependent on the specific problem we're considering?

Comment: @figjuice The transformation $B$ in your first comment is a non-unitary transformation, so if you apply it to the states you will change their norm. I think it's most clear to see what non-unitarity means if you start with some properly normalized states (eg, an orthonormal eigenbasis), then evolve in time with the Schrodinger equation given your Hamiltonian. Then the statement is that the time evolved initial eigenbasis is no longer orthonormal, and that cannot be fixed with a unitary transformation of the states.

Comment: Physically, this means that you started with probabilities summing to 1 and ended with probabilities summing to less than 1 (or godforbid greater than 1). That problem is something wrong with the Hamiltonian you've assumed for time evolution and it's a real physical problem, you can't do a math trick to fix it, since you can actually measure the probabilities.

Comment: For. your second question, I am just speculating, but maybe there's a way you use a process like the Graham-Schmidt procedure -- which generates an orthonormal basis in a vector space -- and use it to make a matrix unitary. However, this process (if it exists) won't be unique and is of questionable use for physics, in general. So in practice, the right way to go from a phenomenological non-unitary description of a system to the correct unitary one  depends on the physical problem.